# For Mandarin, are there estimates on how many repetitions it takes to remember a word through reading?

Tags: vocabulary, chinese, reading

Nation (2014) ([pdf](http://www.nflrc.hawaii.edu/rfl/October2014/articles/nation.pdf)) discusses English vocabulary acquisition through extensive reading alone.  While reading at a 98% comprehensible input level, the learner will (probably) remember a word encountered 12+ times:

> In this study, the moderately safe goal of 12 repetitions is taken as the minimum.  ... enough to allow the opportunity for several dictionary look-ups, several unassisted retrievals, and an opportunity to meet each word in a wide variety of contexts.

However, I'm learning Mandarin Chinese, so I'm wondering if there is similar research in this direction.  Reading in Chinese is rather different to reading in English.

**Question**: For Mandarin, are there estimates on how many repetitions it takes to remember a word through reading?